# How can I use sleep in while without freezing all app?

Tags: swift

I have a while loop which looping until some expression get true for breaking the loop, inside this loop I got a sleep(1), everything works fine, the only problem is the app get frozen until end of the while loop which is logical, I am trying to find out a way that the app would not get frozen while "while" working! Maybe multithreading programming? is it possible?

```
var repeatLoop = true
var count: Int = 0

while repeatLoop {

    print(count)
    count += 1
    sleep(1)
    
    if count >= 10
    {
        repeatLoop = false
    }
  
}

print("finished!")
```

PS: My Goal is finding the Answer for this question rather than changing the  way of solving, I mean there is so many way to get the same result without sleep or while.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Rather than waiting for something let the *expression* notify when it's finished.

Comment: you mean that I do not use If?

Comment: You should never `sleep`

Comment: Yes, polling is bad practice.

Comment: Ok! I know what you are saying, I need to put some kind of delay in each loop, how should do that? I Know about timer or other ways, I am interested to without timer, also I know that I can use many other ways.

Comment: Great, use one of the *many other ways* **without** the loop.

Comment: thanks, so I take it that there is no way with while and sleep to prevent freezing.

Comment: Never sleep. Don't even _think_ about sleeping. Never never never sleep. The end.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? are you waiting for something (then do what vadian says)? or are you counting to 10 in intervals (use Timers then)? or are you delaying execution of something (use DispatchQueue then)?

Comment: thanks, good to know, but why we have sleep at all?

Comment: I would also suggest using `while true` with a `break` to make your code a little more practical

Comment: thanks, that was also good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this program you can't! You need to look for options in your programming framework which can do multi threading. Your sleep() function must allow other threads to run.

One nice solution is to invert the logic and use Timers. instead of call sleep to block the operation till the next interaction. Your timer will call your routine many times you want.

Look this: [The ultimate guide to Timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer)

Answer (score 2):

The app won't freeze if you don't run this code on the main/UI thread.

There are several ways to do this on iOS. Here's one quick way:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async 
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: @Omid What do you mean; what don't you care about wrt your question?

Comment: You both gave me the right answer! which one should I choose?

Comment: @Omid Just choose the answer you like best. Matt gives a bit more details (he was quicker adding that), so good choice.

Comment: I saw he was some sec faster than you, that is why I take that answer, but thanks a lot to as well, I voted your answer instead

Answer (score 2):

The main thread / queue is the interface thread / queue, so time-consuming activity there freezes the interface.

> Maybe multithreading programming

Indeed. The answer to your actual question is: do the time-consuming activity on a *background* thread / queue.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // your code here
}
```

Of course, this raises the spectre of concurrency-related issues involving multiple simultaneous execution of the same code, non-thread-safe conflicts between accesses to shared data, etc. But that is the price of doing time-consuming things, and you just have to learn to cope.